# Why does my fermentation keep stalling?

Tags: fermentation, yeast

Each of my last four batches has stalled well above FG. The first two restarted after bottling and caused bottle bombs.

The last batch was a kolsch with OG 1.047. Wyeast 2565. Stalled at 1.024 for three weeks, even after I raised the temperature to 70F. I pitched a new pack of the same yeast, and 10 days later it was down to 1.004.

This batch is an IPA. 8lb 2-row, 1/2lb Munich, 1/2lb C40. Mashed at 154. OG was 1.072. It was only 2.75 gallons, so I pitched a single pack of Wyeast 1056 at 66F. It blew off about 1 cup in the first two days, then the yeast settled out. After a week it was at 1.020, so I raised the temp to 70F. Four days later it's still at 1.020.

I never had this problem in my first 10 batches. Why might it be happening now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the kolch, that's a pseudo-lager and really needs twice the cell count as an ale.

The ale was an also an underpitch with an OG of 1.072 should have had two packs.

*Edit: Just noticed it was 2.75g, (sorry i've had a few) underpitch shouldn't be the issue on this one. At 154 mash and the crystal could put TG at 1.020.  I suspect maybe mash temp calibration was off with closer to 159 Because of the blow off you noted, making a less fermentable wort.*

To avoid this in the furture. I'd recommend oxygenation with pure o2, and do a starter to grow to proper pitch cell counts.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. The yeast was only 15 days old according to the date stamp. I aerated for 20 minutes with an aquarium pump, which is the most I've done. I don't think my mash temp was that far off, but maybe it was. I guess next time I'll try a starter.

Comment: @JoshYeager I would raise the temp a few more degrees up to 75ish and swirl the fermenter to get the yeast back in suspension. Or you can pitch a lager strain at ale temps which will consume maltotriose a sugar ale strains can't use, may help get the FG lower.

Comment: I raised the temp to 75F and swirled heavily. I've had active bubbles in the airlock and visible yeast in suspension for 3 days. Any idea why the yeast gave up before the first time?

Comment: @JoshYeager the triggers for flocculation arn't completely understood yet. And vary widely among strains. Yeast start to flocculate late growth stage, then reach a point where they stop feeding and don't have those bonds broke mechanically from co2 bouancy. Once they floc they get less cell wall contact to wort and further reduces feeding. Some think that reduction in nutrients, ph change, and ethanol levels play a roll. Sorry but there really isn't an esablished reason for it yet. But microbiologist are working on the puzzle. http://www.wyeastlab.com/clarificationflocculation

Comment: @JoshYeager basically by raising the temp and swirling, you broke much of the flocculation bonds and raised the yeast metabolism to be able to feed again in a "hostile" environment.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It's very weird that the same thing happened with three different yeasts (1968 ESB, 2565 Kolsch, and 1056 American). Maybe something in my setup is causing it. I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: @JoshYeager I think the culprit is low cell count causing it to give up before TG. The trigger for growth to feeding is depletion of O2. You will get much better results using pure O2 and a carb stone, over an aquarium pump. Or keep the pump on for much much longer.